# how to know out of date drupal modules?

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-modules

I have a drupal based website with too many enabled modules, and i need to know what are the modules that have updates?
in other words, i need to update all of my modules to the latest release.
how can i get a list of all of out of date modules and what is the best way to update them?
i think there will be a better choice to update modules than downloading the latest release to **/sites/all/modules** and the run update.php
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, a manual update is the only solution (that I know for sure works in the way it is supposed to work) in Drupal 6.

You get a list of updated modules from the `admin/reports/updates` page.

With Drupal 7, you have the ability you use `admin/reports/updates/update` and update the modules. I haven't had the chance to test that myself but I assume that it should work ok. But still, Drupal core needs to be updated manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH access to your website, consider installing http://drupal.org/project/drush Drush and use the command

> drush pm-update

If all goes well, your site has the latest versions of all modules and Drupal itself upgraded in less than 5 minutes. Make sure to create a backup of the site before, however (modules and database).